# How do I plot a family of functions?

Tags: plotting, homework

[image]

I don't know how to plot these functions in Mathematica. Please show me how to do it.

Comment: Do you know how to plot just *one* of these functions in *Mathematica*? If not, look up the documentation for `Plot` and `Piecewise`. If you do, then just make a `Table` of the `Plots` and use `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsGrid` or `GraphicsColumn`. The documentation for each of these functions is pretty good. So start there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will show you how to implement the most difficult of the four cases you show in your question. It will be up to you study this example and use it as a model for writing the other cases on your own.

```
Psi[n_, T_, i_][t_] /; EvenQ[i] && 2 <= i <= n - 2 :=
  Module[{h = T/n},
    Piecewise[
      {{(t - (i - 1) h) (t - (i - 2) h)/(2 h^2), (i - 2) h <= t <= i h},
       {(t - (i + 1) h) (t - (i + 2) h)/(2 h^2), i h <= t <= (i + 2) h}},
      0]]
```

Then

```
Plot[Psi[4, 1, 2][t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot1]

and

```
Plot[Psi[5, 2, 2][t], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: plot2]

For you, there may be much new Mathematica material in the above function definition. But you will need to master the new material if you want to be able to implement functions of the kind your textbook is describing.

At least, now you know what functions to look up in Mathematica documentation. I will give you a hint: to learn about `/;`, look up `Condition`.

Comment: @karthickmaths. No, sorry, I do not share my email address on-line. Also, I am not a Mathematica consultant.

Comment: @karthickmaths. Please put that one problem before the community by posting it as a new question. That's the way this site works. I might answer it, or somebody else might. Don't try to rely on one person.